# How to check if two objects have the same class in Kotlin?

Tags: class, kotlin

In Kotlin, you can check if an object is an instance of a class (including inheritance) using `is`

```
myObject is String
```

But how can you check, if two objects are of the **exact** same class? I am searching for an analogue to Python's

```
type(obj1) is type(obj2)
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can get the type of an object with [`::class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references), and compare those:

```
val sameClass = obj1::class == obj2::class
```

More specifically, [this section](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-class-references-since-11) of the above documentation describes that `::class` on an object gives you exactly what you want, the exact class of the instance you're calling it on.